# How to take account of the variable number of contributions of statistical individuals in a ROC curve?

Tags: roc

Consider data of patients in an hospital. For each stay, we have a score from 0 to 100 and the presence or absence of a diagnosis.

We want to draw a ROC curve where a threshold on the score will predict the presence of the disease.

Suppose now that each patient could have one or multiple stays, is it possible to include data of all stays, or is it better to use only one stay per patient?

If only one stay could be used what kind of arguments will lead to choose the first stay or the last stay?

I have difficulties to know what the statistical individual is. Is it the patient, the stay or the measure of the score?

Comment: Are you trying to characterize the patient or the hospital visit?

Comment: I want to characterize the patient at a certain point in time.

Comment: ROC curves have to do with the probability of a category. It does not sound like you’re trying to predict the probability of a category.

Comment: @Dave ROC curves do not have to be a probability at all. You just have to be able to rank the data by a category, albeit probability is one measurement that can be ranked. Our highly voted threads on how to construct ROC curves should make it clear why this is the case.

Comment: Would you not want there to be something categorical in order to have the idea of “true positive” and “false” positive to graph? I get the idea that you slide some threshold to adjust what you call a positive and a negative class and that the threshold does not have to be a probability, though.

Comment: @Dave I have tried to edit the question to answer your point.